# cypress how to check if checkboxes childrens are selected

Tags: checkbox, cypress

when I expand a checkbox parent which contains list of checkboxes , want to loop over all checkboxes to ensure only few of them are selected:

```js
//expand parent
// select checkbox1
cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox1"]').check({ force: true });
// select checkbox 5
cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox5"]').check({ force: true });

//close then expand again
```

Question : How to easily loop over all checkboxes under parent to check only checkbox1 and 5 (by name) are selected ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:checked` pseudo-selector, see [:checked Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) which selects just the previously checked items.

```js
//expand parent
// select checkbox1
cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox1"]').check({ force: true });
// select checkbox 5
cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox5"]').check({ force: true });

//close then expand again 

cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
  .then($checked => [...$checked].map(el => el.getAttribute('aria-label')))
  .should('deep.eq', ['checkbox1', 'checkbox5'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are having trouble figuring out how to use `.each()` on the checkboxes, just assert the checked value directly.

See [examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check#Check-an-invisible-checkbox)

```js
cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox1"]')
  .check({ force: true })
  .should('be.checked')

cy.get('[aria-label="checkbox2"]')
  .should('not.be.checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `^` selector to select all elements that begin with a certain value.

```js
cy.get('[aria-label^="checkbox"]');
```

This should yield all of your elements with an aria-label of `checkbox*`. You can then use `cy.each()` to iterate through each of those elements and selectively take an action depending on the `aria-label` value, using JQuery's `.attr()` function.

```js
cy.get('[aria-label^="checkbox"]').each(($el) => {
  if ($el.attr('aria-label') === 'checkbox1' 
      || $el.attr('aria-label') === 'checkbox5') {
    // validation or action here here
  } else {
    // other validation or action here
  }
});
```

In the above `cy.each()`, you can re-insert the yielded element into a Cypress command chain via `cy.wrap($el)`.

Comment: it's just an example here, all checkboxes have different names and don't have same prefix,...etc

Comment: Can you update your question with a more realistic HTML snippet?